# Get Users App-Scoped user id in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

In advent of the new V2 Facebook Open Graph API, I need to make note of the logged in users 'App-Scoped' user ID, in order to register the id with Parse in order to receive PUSH notifications.

However, as the logged in user I get the Facebook ID instead.

Haven't found anything in the docs to solve this problem yet, so thought I better ask here.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue with a new app. All friends' user_ids are app-scoped, but the user_id for the current user is the "real" one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. If you created your facebook application before the introduction of graph API 2.0, It will continue to receive the canonical facebook user ID
2. If you created your facebook application, after the introduction of graph API 2.0, It gives you app scoped id instead of the canonical id.

In this case I assume your application is quite old.Therefor create a new app and it will give you the app scope id.

Comment: What happens if the version 1.0 is switched off? (April 2015)

Comment: In this case user's ID will be changed on next reinstalling an application

Comment: Actually the user's ID will never be changed.  Anyone who access your app (for the first time) with v1.x API will always have the same ID as will anyone who access your app (for the first time) with v2.x

Answer (score 2):

In facebook document:

> "The id of this person's user account. This ID is unique to each app
>   and cannot be used across different apps. Our upgrade guide provides
>   more info about this." You only get id with each apps.

more information in here: [facebook.developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/)

Answer (score 1):

The "Facebook ID" as you call it **IS** the App-scoped User ID.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

Comment: Yea that's what I thought, but we've been testing this by creating a new User etc. and it this wasn't the case. So thinking that maybe it isn't enabled yet OR it only applies for friend IDs

Comment: I don't understand...What did you test, and what was the outcome?

Comment: We created a test user, then logged into our app and called the api call to get the logged in users ID, but it returned the actual Facebook ID, rather than a scoped ID contrary to what the documentation clearly states.

Comment: How can you determine if it's the "real ID" as you call it, and the App-scoped ID?

Comment: Well, maybe that's the behaviour for Test Users. At least, there's nothing in the docs about that. You should take the ID Facebook returns. I don't see the problem here to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

The id you get from the api's is an opaque string, and you should use it as such. 
If the user has already granted your app access on v1, then your app will continue to receive the same id.

Comment: Do you know if the UID returned from using the native iOS Facebook SDK will also return the 'Opaque' id, presumably a App-Scoped user id (Assuming the user created an account post v2.0 API) in the same fashion?

Comment: This will be the same across all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

The old users who have registered keep receiving the canonical ID from Facebook for those users, and new users are getting the new scoped ID. Although it is working fine as a long integer, I suggest to change the long field for a string field (unless you already treat it as a string), because we cannot know what Facebook will send here in the future. To keep your code mainly unchanged, create a new internal user id long integer which will be the one your code is already using, and relate it with the string ID from Facebook, which is canonical or scoped, depending if the user registered before or after the migration, and which you will have to manage only for logins, requests, open graph stories, etc.

This way you have not worry about canonical or scoped id EXCEPT one case. Everything works fine, except we found a problem, and maybe somebody can correct me and so help me to solve this: when a new user accept a invite request from an existing user, when your app reads the ID of the sender of the request, I found that Facebook gives you the new scoped id ALWAYS, no mater if the referrer is old or new user. This way, if a user registered before the migration, you have stored the canonical ID, and later, you read a request from this user accepted for a new one, you get the scoped id from the old user, but what you have stored is the canonical one! As result, old users can no more invite new users properly! If anyone knows how getting canonical ids from requests sent for old users, or knows how to obtain the scoped ids for the existing users with canonical ids (to store the new scoped ids in the database) it would be very helpful to hear their suggestions.