# Corona SDK Facebook returns app_scoped_id and not my normal user_id

Tags: facebook-graph-api, coronasdk

If I have understood it correctly Facebook made some changes so it returns app_scoped_id instead of the normal user_id.

The problem I have now is that no other function seems to work.

I receive an I id from Facebook, and it's the same each time I login, but if I use facebook.request("me/friends") the table is empty, if I use facebook.showDialog("friends") it

What do I need to do in Corona SDK to get this to work? Before I could use these functions after having setup them up in Facebook.

I read this thread explaining why this happen but it doesn't explain how to solve it in Corona SDK: [Get Users App-Scoped user id in Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601875/get-users-app-scoped-user-id-in-facebook-graph-api/24010055#24010055)

Comment: "if I use facebook.showDialog("friends") it"...? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Facebook API v2.0, friends list (/me/friend) returns **ONLY** user's friends who are already using your application. This limitation applies to all apps that are on v1.0 mode too.

If you're looking to get friends for tagging actions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends

If you're looking to get friends for inviting to a Facebook Game on Canvas: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, with this information I know how to proceed!