# How to load Facebook cover photo via graphRequest with a higher resolution? [Android | Facebook v2.3]

Tags: android, facebook, photo

I am writing an Android app where I need the user to log in with Facebook.

Login works fine and I also get a profile picture, but the resolution of the picture is very low - about 50 px x 50 px. Is there a possibility to get a better one?

The following code is used to load the image, after the Facebook login process and a `GraphRequest.newMeRequest`.

```
public class LoadFacebookUserPicture extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Context context;

    public LoadFacebookUserPicture (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("test.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("LoadFacebookUserPicture", e.getMessage());
        }
        Log.e("LoadFacebookUserPicture", "Passt");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the request, within the class LoadFacebookUserPicture is called.

```
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        currentAccessToken,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Save facebook data
                                SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.userdata_facebook), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                                try {
                                    // Lese von FB json objekt
                                    int fb_id = ((JSONObject) object).getInt("id");
                                    String fb_name = ((JSONObject) object).getString("name");
                                    String fb_gender = ((JSONObject) object).getString("gender");
                                    String fb_link = ((JSONObject) object).getString("link");
                                    JSONObject json_data = ((JSONObject) object).getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");
                                    String fb_picture_url = json_data.getString("url");
                                    // Schreibe in private shared pref der activity
                                    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.fb_user_id), fb_id);
                                    editor.putString(getString(R.string.fb_user_name), fb_name);
                                    editor.putString(getString(R.string.fb_user_gender), fb_gender);
                                    editor.putString(getString(R.string.fb_user_link), fb_link);
                                    editor.putString(getString(R.string.fb_user_picture_url), fb_picture_url);
                                    editor.commit();

                                    String[] params = new String[1];
                                    params[0] = fb_picture_url;
                                    new LoadFacebookUserPicture(MainActivity.this).execute(params);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday,gender,link,picture");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant api please

Comment: Facebook SDK v2.3
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Comment: what i request was the string you get for "url " ..

Comment: Here´s the url:
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/11147581_1375762972753721_1548057398797879291_n.jpg?oh=7a44389acb79c6d7dbe9fbb53c5c8718&oe=55E4B0B8&__gda__=1436348469_85fce3ee80eacb997f0f50f76c40821b

Comment: I get it from 
((JSONObject) object).getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");
within the callback method, after 
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest

Comment: post where you call this class "LoadFacebookUserPicture" please

Comment: @Heshan Sandeepa: I post the call in the answer below.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: remove the answer, you cant put it like that. I have edit your question

Comment: I tried it with the url you mentioned: http://graph.facebook.com/2147483647/picture?type=large

But I get following Exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://graph.facebook.com/2147483647/picture?type=large

Comment: this should work , if you provided the correct id ,  verify ur own profile id from here and try to get the image http://findmyfacebookid.com/

Comment: I understand and with the fb_id it works fine.
But with the id, I get in my application (see fb_id) it is not working! 
How do I get this id from facebook, when paring my GraphRequest.newMeRequest????
Thank you for your patience!

Comment: i hope you are getting a relevant facebook profile id with "((JSONObject) object).getInt("id");" , if so it should work

Comment: I hope your problem is something else, read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601875/get-users-app-scoped-user-id-in-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this , This will get you a much better image

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<fb_id >/picture?type=large
```

Comment: Is fb_id the id, which the user get through my application 
or the originally id of the user from facebook.
Sorry for the question but I new to this.

I tried it with the user_id, which the user gets from my application,

Comment: But this field don´t come up with my request,
I only get an id from my application.
 int fb_id = ((JSONObject) object).getInt("id");

Comment: so, it doesnt matter. you will get relevant picture according to the id

Comment: Working great, thanks! The only thing - to make it work with Glide - change http to https.