# How to retrieve the canonical user id for facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am creating an android app which needs to be converted a web site to mobile app. On website Users can login using facebook. So I integrated facebook login in android app successfully and login function works(only for recently signed up accounts).

I checked accounts which signed up about 1 year ago using web site, but the login failed on mobile app.

The reason I think is, earlier accounts uses canonical facebook user ids(before graph api v2) and recent accounts(after graph api v2) use the app scoped user ids.[read the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601875/get-users-app-scoped-user-id-in-facebook-graph-api)

**Note: Users are stored using user id in the backend. So the user id i'm getting from app has to be matched with the stored id(which is canonical user id) for successful login.**

**The problem is how to get that canonical user id for earlier accounts?**

I found that to get the user ids for different apps facebook has introduced [this business mapping API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business) . To use this API I need to create a new business and need to define both web app and android app under the same business then I can retrieve both ids separately.

**If someone use this business mapping API, can I retrieve that canonical user id from this API call?**

**or if someone suggest a way to solve this login problem for earlier accounts, it will be really appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Even if your App was created with v1.0 of the Graph API, you will still get the "old" (real) ID of users with `/me`. There is no need to map anything, except if you want to match users between different Apps. That´s what the Business Mapping API is for.

Comment: is v1 still available? if so how to use that in android?

Comment: no, it is not. but if a user authorized the app back in the old days, he will keep the old id. existing user ids don´t just get upgraded to app scoped ids. you don´t need v1.0 anyway, the app scoped user id can be used in exactly the same way.

Comment: that is the problem. Im getting a different user id from android app. any idea for this??and when i passed that id to server side, it doesn't have such id stored. so  user can not login. this happens only for older accounts

Comment: if you get a different user id, then that user never authorized the app. or he deauthorized it in the past, could be that he got an app scoped id then, but it´s very unlikely.

Comment: either way, it should not happen to existing users. if it does, you should file a bug.

Comment: i will check it and let you know

Comment: But your Android app definitively uses the same app id as your website?